# Set form value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I set a value here

```
<input type="text" name="3b9bcc77d6b729eaa82d68a5768edfca" value="" class="textCtrl" id="ctrl_3b9bcc77d6b729eaa82d68a5768edfca" autofocus="true" autocomplete="off">
```

I tried with this code

```
document.getElementById('ctrl_2bf2afd36152a19957d999bc7a32064e').value = 'cccc';
```

but anything appends.
ps. I used this extension for Chrome for injecting JavaScript code
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija

Comment: are you enabling the host to be used with cjs?

Answer (score 0):

Your `id` for the input field doesn't match the `id` you specified in `document.getElementById('ctrl_2bf2afd36152a19957d999bc7a32064e').value = 'cccc';`

For your case it should be `document.getElementById('ctrl_3b9bcc77d6b729eaa82d68a5768edfca').value = 'cccc';`